# Search Vietnamese word with 'no-symbol' string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server DB with something like:

```
Name
------
phòng
phóng
phong
phao
phim
```

I would like to write thing like:

```
select * from table where name like 'pho%'
```

and it will return first 3 rows.

In MySQL the above script work, but not on SQL Server.
What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that you want the `LIKE` comparison to be accent insensitive (and usually case insensitive as well):

```
select * from table 
where name like 'pho%' COLLATE [Vietnamese_CI_AI]
```

To get a list of accent insensitive collations:

```
select * from fn_helpcollations()
where name like '%AI%' and name like 'viet%'
```

Collation `Vietnamese_CI_AI` is

> Vietnamese, case-insensitive, accent-insensitive,
>   kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive

Comment: Should that be accent insensitive collation as well?

Comment: Probably `Vietnamese_CI_AI`, but see [here](http://lab.artlung.com/sql-server-collations/)...